# How to use map stl within struct data structure and initialize the map and then reference to it?

Tags: c++, struct, stl

Is it correct method to have map within struct and then having array of structure.

```
struct node    {             //struct node
    std::map<int ,int> mymap;//stl map within struct
};
struct node n[10];           //array of struct node
```

Then how to initialise n and refer to map within it?
How to have iterator to map within struct that is mymap?
any best way?

Comment: `mymap` is default construct so is empty (it is valid).

Answer (score 1):

Bad or good idea is opinion-based. However, it is not wrong.

`std::map` does not need to be initialized. The default constructor will do it for you.

How to access your map ?

```
for(size_t i=0;i<10;++i){
    n[i].mymap//.something
}
```

Comment: how to have iterator to the mymap

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node n[10];
```

Creates an array of 10 `node`s that are default initialized.  Since `std::map` has a default constructor each `node` in `n` will have the map default constructed.

To access the map you just use

```
n[some_valid_index].mymap//.some_member_function;
```

Remember that arrays are 0 index based so `some_valid_index` needs to be in the range of `[0, 9]`

Comment: How to use iterator to map within struct?

Comment: @Shubhamgupta I Don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: how to use map<int ,int >:: iterator it to mymap

Comment: @Shubhamgupta `auto it = n[some_valid_index].mymap.begin();`

Answer (score 0):

There is an example static initialisztion:

```
node n[3] = {
    {
        { {1,2}, {3,4} }
    },
    {
        { {1,2}, {3,4} }
    },
    {
        { {1,2}, {3,4} }
    }
};
```

remove "struct" before n declaration.
and about accessing map elements like this:

```
n[1].mymap[1] // = 2
n[2].mymap[3] // = 4
```

need to specify modern c++ language standart, for gcc command line will be like this:

```
g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp
```